# How to prevent LibreOffice running 'recover' at each startup, on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

How to prevent LibreOffice running 'recover' at each start-up?

On Ubuntu, each time I restart my computer, and then start LibreOffice, it asks me whether I want to recover documents. It does this even though I've turned off automatic backups.

Other editors, such as gedit don't have this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop`.
2. Replace `Exec=libreoffice --writer %U` with `Exec=libreoffice --writer --norestore %U`.

Comment: whoa, 11 year old question lol :P

Answer (score 4):

Adding the option '--norestore' when running libreoffice gets rid of the recovery dialog.

This can be made to happen systematically by adding the following to your .bashrc:

```
alias libreoffice="libreoffice --norestore"
```

Comment: that just made my libreoffice crash

Comment: How do you make this a default behaviour in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

I have not found a clean solution to this problem. This is what I am using as a workaround on **Ubuntu 18.04**. For the command line:

```
alias libreoffice="libreoffice --norestore"
```

For UI elements I open the following folder with nautilus,

```
sudo nautilus /usr/share/applications
```

and edit the properties of the 6 links to the LibreOffice apps to call libreoffice with `--norestore`

[image: File Properties Dialog]

The changes seem to be persistent although there is no `Save` button.
IMHO this should be configurable in libreoffice and I will file a bug report/feature request as soon as  I find time.